# how to find if binomial coefficient C(n,r) is divisible by n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

My question is whether there is a simple criteria to determine whether n divides C(n,r). For example if n is prime or more generally,  g.c.d of n and r equals 1 , then n divides C(n,r).A naive method is to compute C(n,r) mod n. is there any simpler way without evaluating C(n,r) mod n .

Comment: When I tried to [search a bit](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n%5Cmid%20%5Cbinom%20nk%24&p=1), I found that there are some posts which seem related. For example,
[When is $\binom{n}{k}$ divisible by $n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/545962) and 
[Conditions for which $n | {n \choose k} $for all $k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/713685)